# Clickhouse - is it possible to Alter table in a cluster in 1 command

Tags: database, clickhouse, yandex

I have a scenario where we need to add columns on a table which exists in several different Clickhouse nodes and queried by a distributed table .

Is there a way to alter that table in all servers, using a single alter command? meaning that the alter command will propagate to all various instances and fail completely if one node fails to commit alter?
or do I need to develop a mechanism which knows to run alter on each node, and rollback if one node fails to commit alter?

Answer (score 7):

alter table xxx **on cluster my_cluster** add column x Int64;

alter table xxx_dist **on cluster my_cluster** add column x Int64;